# How to parse URLs using urlparse and split() in python?

Tags: python, urlparse

Could someone explain to me the purpose of this line `host = parsed.netloc.split('@')[-1].split(':')[0]`in the following code? I understand that we are trying to get the host name from netlock but I don't understand why we are splitting with the @ delimiter and then again with the : delimiter.

```
import urlparse
parsed = urlparse.urlparse('https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs')
print parsed
host = parsed.netloc.split('@')[-1].split(':')[0]
print host


Result:

ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.google.co.uk', path='/search', params='', query='client=ubuntu&channel=fs, fragment='')

www.google.co.uk
```

Surely if one just needs the domain, we can get that from urlparse.netloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netloc in its full form can have HTTP authentication credentials and a port number:

```
login:password@www.google.co.uk:80
```

See [RFC1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808.html#section-2.1) and [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.1)

So we potentially have to split that into `["login:password", "www.google.co.uk:80"]`, take the last part, split that into `["www.google.co.uk", "80"]` and take the hostname.

If these parts are omitted, there's no harm in trying to split on nonexisting delimeters, and no need to check if they're omitted or not.

[`urlparse` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse-result-object)